# Firstly show list then hide it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I write code by using css and JS which gonna firstly show list then hide it. But i cant do that someone can help me to improve it?

**HTML**

```
<ul id="myDIV"> 
  <img src="Messenger/AWTzuJu8q-E.png" onclick="myFunction()">
  <li>arman</li> 
  <li>arman</li> 
  <li>arman</li> 
  <li>arman</li> 
</ul>
```

**Javascript**

```
    function myFunction() {
      if (document.getElementById("myDIV").style.overflow = "hidden") {
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style.overflow = "visible"
      } else if(document.getElementById("myDIV").style.overflow = "visible") {
        document.getElementById("myDIV").style.overflow = "hidden"
      }
    }
```

**CSS**

```
#myDIV {width: 41px;height: 28px;overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: I'm not gonna downvote you since you are new on Stack Overflow. But please read the "how-to-ask" guide.

Comment: Offtopic: Stop being this mean towards new members, go show just person some love and upvote :)

Comment: @Artur Hope my answer below helps you. Don't worry about the down votes & welcome to StackOverflow! Happy coding!

Comment: So.. you want to firstly show .. then hide the post/content after some seconds? like.. hide after 5 seconds...

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code doesn't work? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception, post the line it occurred on and the exception details.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of `style.overflow`, just use `style.display`. Also, `==` must be used in `if` condition for comparison instead of `=`.

> Use `style.display = "none";` instead of `style.overflow = "hidden";`
>
> Use `style.display = "block";` instead of `style.overflow =
>   "visible";`

Difference between `overflow` & `display`

> **overflow**
>
> The overflow property specifies what happens if content overflows an
>   element's box.
>
> - **`visible`** The overflow is not clipped. It renders outside the element's box. This is the default value.
> - **`hidden`**  The overflow is clipped, and the rest of the content will be invisible.
>
> **display**
>
> - **`block`** Displays an element as a block element.
> - **`none`** The element will not be displayed at all (has no effect on layout).

For more information, refer [Mozilla/display](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) & [Mozilla/overflow](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/overflow)

**Edit** - You are using `if...else` in a wrong way. Please refer [Mozilla/if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

In your case, your function will be like this (Please read my comments).

```
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display == "none") {  // If hidden, set display to block to show list
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "block";
  } else {  // If visible, set display to none to hide list
    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: i tried like this but its not work,  i get it right yes?
function myFunction() {
   if(document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "none")
      {document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "visible"}
      }
   else(document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "visible")
       {document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display = "hidden"}

Comment: Use `==` in your `if` statement for comparison instead of just `=`. For `display` property, use `block` instead of `visible` & `none` instead of `hidden`.

Comment: @ArturGevorgian Please check the updated `function` above & read the comments for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand what you want to achieve how ever if you simply want to hide it on click then try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<ul id="myDIV" onclick="myFunction()"> 
  <li>arman</li> 
  <li>arman</li> 
  <li>arman</li> 
  <li>arman</li> 
</ul>

<script>
function myFunction() {

 if(document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display= "none"){

    document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display= "visible"
}
else if(document.getElementById("myDIV").style.diaplay= "visible"){

  document.getElementById("myDIV").style.display= "none"
}}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```